# Can I publish a paid suspended Android App from another account as free?

Tags: android, google-play

A few days ago I published an App on Google Play for the first time.

That App was my very first App I ever made.

So that was my first experience with App development and first experience with Google Play.

That App is basically an App version of a Facebook fan page that I own and administer. That is how I access my Facebook Page through WebView **"mWebview.loadUrl("http://touch.facebook.com/mypageid");"**. Would this be enough to let the Google Play know that I own that page? I made it a paid version just for sake of learning, what a merchant account is and how it is created. I set the price less than a pound and was intending to make it free after it is published.

But that App got suspended and was never published because of copyright infringements despite I had mentioned many times that we don't own any copyrights for anything.

I read in a thread on this website that free Apps don't need to be copyright protected because I am not making money over unauthorized stuff.

Now the question is **"Can I UN-publish this App?**

as I can see an option for unpublishable the App at the top **and then publish the same App as a free App from the same Google Account?**" 
OR

**"Can I publish the same App from another Google Account as a free version?"**

I also read that Google stores the names of the Package so it will instantly know that that particular App is a suspended one and won't allow the App to be published and may also terminate my Google account.

Another question is **"what changes do I need to make to make it different from the previous one?"**

I'd be grateful if someone helps me out in a simple way because I cannot find a straight forward answer to these questions anywhere.

Comment: You can't publish it anywhere because "we don't own any copyrights for anything".

Comment: @StephaneMathis I mean the photographs :P as an FB fan page usually shared photosgraphs with fans :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unpublish your app, near the top of one of your app’s pages, click **Unpublish** app. When you unpublish an app, existing users can still use your app and receive app updates. Your app won’t be available for new users to find and download on Google Play.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476

Please note that according to [Google Play Developer Program Policies](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html), it's not allowed to publish apps that provide a WebView of a website you don't own or administer:

> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to:
>
> Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do so)

Reference: http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Comment: "it's not allowed to publish apps that provide a WebView of a website you don't own or administer:" That's an excellent piece of information since I didn't know that. I have a WebView for my Facebook fan page that I own and administer, a Webview for Google and Wikipedia. Now I know and thanks to you that I don't have the rights to provide a WebView for Google and Wikipedia. But how can I prove to Google that I do own and administer this Facebook fan page? Would you please guide me on that one too. Facebook pages usually share photos and videos from WWW, so how can I get permissions for them.

Comment: Hello Aygul. That is how I access my Facebook Page through WebView "mWebview.loadUrl("http://touch.facebook.com/mypageid");", Would this be enough to let the Google Play know that I own that page? Also can I keep the name of my App or do I need to change it? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid they might mean that you should own/administer the whole page, namely, Facebook in this particular case. Since your Facebook page still belongs to Facebook.

Comment: If I remove the WebView and let the fan page open in any browser e-g Chrome, would that be OK?

Comment: And do I still need to provide the Facebook Page ID even if I let it open through chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer all your questions one by one.

> Can I UN-publish this App?

Yes you absolutely can.

> then publish the same App as a free App from the same Google Account?

Yes, this is what you should do. But remember to change the package name of your application. It should not be same as the previous suspended app. Just open your manifest file to change it.

> Can I publish the same App from another Google Account as a free
>   version?

Yes you can. But it is better to publish it from the same account on a different package name.

> what changes do I need to make to make it different from the previous
>   one?

If there is anything inside the app that violates copyright, then those things obviously. Otherwise just changing the package name is enough.

**UPDATE**

Yes, its absolutely fine to load your page in a WebView like that. No copyright issue at all. And you can keep your previous app name, there is no need of any change on that.

Its off-topic but still as you asked, about the photos and videos you took from the Internet, there should be no copyright issue if you just mention the source from where you took it. You need to credit the owner or the source and you should not face any copyright issue in Google Play Store any more.

Comment: thank you for your detailed and helpful answer. Since that's an App for a facebook fan page about a celebrity and fan pages usually share photographs and videos from WWW so I am not sure how can I get copyright permissions for them. Would you be able to guide me on that too?

Comment: Hello Aritra. That is how I access my Facebook Page through WebView "mWebview.loadUrl("http://touch.facebook.com/mypageid");", Would this be enough to let the Google Play know that I own that page? Also can I keep the name of my App or do I need to change it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Aritria. Where should I mention the source or credit the owner?

Comment: You should do that in the individual posts in your Facebook page, where you have taken any external media which should be credited.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, then please consider accepting or upvoting the answer. It took a lot of time and effort to write such a detailed answer.

Comment: I am sorry Aritra the App got suspended again. I have already upvoted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just change your application package name. Go to your manifest file and change the package name. That will do IMO.